# Ipython Notebook server running, but can't load the page

Tags: ipython, firewall

I have installed ipython and the server seems to run OK, no error, last line is:
"Use Ctrl-C to stop this server..."

However, the browser just won't load the html page, it always says "The server at .... is taking too long to respond..."

I checked my firewall settings and both my "domain" and "private network" are not connected, and the "inbound connection" is not allowed.

I'm guessing this is causing of ipython notebook to fail to load the page. But I'm not sure..so wanted to see if there's anything I set up wrong with the installation.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of system are you on? Do you have any extra internet security software installed? Sophos in particular is known to cause some problems. Also, try switching the address between `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` - sometimes one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: I'm on Windows7. I have McAfee as the anti-virus software. I did try switching the ips, but no luck for either...

Comment: Can you run `ipython notebook --debug` and paste the log into a pastebin so we can look at more detail of what's going on?

Comment: to add to the issue description, I also just cannot access `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1`. I checked the `..\etc\hosts` file, it is blank. Not sure if can provide more info, and maybe another direction for troubleshooting